# logging into the MATCHBOOK API with Python Requests

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, restful-authentication

I am trying (legitimately and with the go ahead from the site)to log into the betting exchange matchbook.com through their api.

The documentation states:

To Login: https://www.matchbook.com/bpapi/rest/security/session

and

Example Request
POST /security/session
{
 "username": "j_henry",
 "password": "******"
}

Example Response
{
 "session-token": "1418_1234567890",
 "user-id": 1418,
 "account": { // Same as GET /account API response.
 ...
 }
}

I am using Requests and have the following code:

```
payload = {"username": "********", "password": "************"}
r = requests.post('https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/security/session', data=payload)
print (r.status_code)
```

I get error code 415? I must be getting the wrong type of response??

I have looked at a lot of very similar posts on here, and I am about to ask matchbook's team, but before I do has anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to specify `Content-Type`, try to add a header to tell the server it's JSON formatted:

```
payload = {"username": "********", "password": "************"}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json;"}
r = requests.post('https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/security/session', data=payload, headers=headers)
print (r.status_code)
```

Comment: it actually took both of your suggestions Shane and danyamachine to make this work - but it is now singing sweetly and returning 200 :D

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear from your code that you are JSON-encoding your payload. The endpoint is likely expecting JSON. 
Try this:
`payload = '{"username": "********", "password": "************"}'`

Comment: thanks for your help - posting a thankyou coz it actually took both yours and Shane's solution to make this work